# How can i retrive a text from a custom field

Tags: custom-field

I retrieve the date of an actor by selecting the date. `'data_nasterii'` is the name of the custom field.

```
<?php $data = get_field('data_nasterii'); echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data)); ?>
```

If i do not select anyting, I'd like to return: `N/A`  for the actor birthday.
How can I integrate in this code?

If there's a value:
Ex: Birthday :22/11/1978

If I don't select anything I want:
Birthday: N/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what an empty `get_field` returns, as it's from a plugin.

However, assuming it provides `FALSE` or an empty string:

```
<?php
$data = get_field( 'data_nasterii' );
echo ( $data ? date( "d/m/Y", strtotime( $data ) ) : 'N/A' );
?>
```

Comment: No problem. Please click the tick next to my answer so other people know it works.